# Capturing an IP Address with Ajax involved

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo, ip

I have a button that when pressed, allows the user to see a catalog. I am not collecting any information from the user at this point. I am only collecting what catalog they downloaded. I would like to change this to collect their IP Addresses to insert into my database.

Would all I have to do is create a variable in my PHP file like this:
`$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

Then add it into my PDO statement for inserting into the db?

I have read that many recommend checking `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` as well. How could I check both and assign it to the one variable?

Am I doing this correctly?

AJAX

```
$('.downloadButton').on('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'downloadCatalogSend.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            catalog_name: catalog_name,
            button_triggered: button_triggered
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $catalog_download_insert = "INSERT INTO catalog_download_now
                (catalog_name, button_triggered, date_sent, $ip)
                VALUES(?, ?, NOW(), ?)
            ";
    $catalog_download_stmt = $con->prepare($catalog_download_insert);
    $catalog_download_stmt->execute(array($catalog_name, $button_triggered, $ip));

    $hasError = false;

    echo $hasError;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the null coalesce operator:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

This will prefer HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR (the client IP if the request came from a proxy) if it is set, else fall back to REMOTE_ADDR (the actual IP the request came from.)

Caveat: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be easily forged by the client.

Also note, you have this:

```
$catalog_download_insert = "INSERT INTO catalog_download_now
            (catalog_name, button_triggered, date_sent, $ip)
            VALUES(?, ?, NOW(), ?)
        ";
```

Drop that dollar sign from `$ip` -- that should be the field name, not the value you're trying to store in it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help, it works perfectly. BTW - thanks for seeing my typo.

Comment: Also, `X-Forwarded-Forwarded-For:` has been deprecated in favor of [`Forwarded:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded).

Comment: @Sammitch Are you saying I should chaged `Fordwarded-For` to `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]` ?

Comment: At this point in time you'd probably have to check both, and the `Forwarded:` header has a different format entirely. But honestly, you shouldn't bother looking at the proxy headers at all unless you have a specific reason to. As Alex noted they're incredibly easy to spoof, and you should only ever use them if you _explicitly trust_ the proxy that has set them. eg: your CDN

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the info!